# Category view with contents of [gallery]s shown

Tags: categories, images, gallery, excerpt

SO:

I have a bunch of Posts with [gallery]s in them.  They are in category "Galleries".

I want the category view to show (some||all) of the contents of the galleries in each post.  Instead it seems to be stripping out or not rendering the gallery at all.  Ideally I'd like to be able to control home much of the gallery is excerpted, but anything will do, really.

This seems like it would be a common request, but i can't find anything on it.  Help and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `[gallery]` shortcode (just like any other shortcode) is displayed when `the_content()` is used to display the post content, and normally themes do this in single template.

In themes, normally, insted of print the content is used `the_excerpt()` that strips out html and shortcodes.

Sure you can edit your category archive  to use `the_content()` instead of `the_excerpt()`, but in this case all the post content is printed in the archive.

But it seems to me that you want to use the gallery as excerpt (show the gallery shortcode instead of the standard `the_excerpt()`).

Now, your category template (`category.php`) should contain something like that (semplified):

```
while( have_posts() ) :  the_posts();

   the_title();
   the_excerpt();

endwhile;
```

So you can use `'the_excerpt'` filter to output the shortcode when in galleries archive and when some other codition is reached (e.g. for first X number of posts).

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'maybe_excerpt_gallery');

function maybe_excerpt_gallery($excerpt) {
  global $post, $wp_query;
  if ( is_category() && in_category('galleries', $post) && $wp_query->current_post < 5 ) {
    $gallery = get_the_post_gallery_shortcode($post);
    return $gallery ? $gallery : $excerpt;
  }
}
```

Some themes, use something like `the_content( 'Continue reading...' )` in archives, in this case add the same filter to `the_content`: once the function check if we are on 'galleries' category archive, `the_content` function in other parts in theme will not be affected.

Before you go searching codex for `get_the_post_gallery_shortcode` function, I have to advice you that... this function does **not** exists in WordPress, but let's write it:

```
function get_the_post_gallery_shortcode( $post ) {
  if ( empty($post) ) global $post;
  if ( empty($post) || ! isset($post->post_content) ) return false;
  if (
    preg_match_all( '/'. get_shortcode_regex() .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches )
    && array_key_exists( 2, $matches ) && in_array( 'gallery', $matches[2] )
  ) {
    foreach ( $matches[2] as $i => $sc ) {
      if ( $sc == 'gallery' ) return do_shortcode( $matches[0][$i] );
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

I've used the [get_shortcode_regex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex) to check and extract the shortcode (code for great part stolen from codex) and output it if found.

Now when you visit your *galleries* category archive, the first 5 posts will have the gallery (if exists) as excerpt .

Comment: Thanks! - It is always nice when you think "Golly, somebody should write an article about this", you ask your question on SO, and somebody writes that article 15 minutes later.

Comment: You are welcome @TrassVasston. Let me know if it works, I've not tested ;)

Comment: Works great - I stuck the code near the header, modified the category name and systems go.  For some reason a style was set in the theme to hide the image anyway, so beware of that.

Comment: good place for this code should be `functions.php`... leave templates as clean as possible is always a good idea. @TrassVasston